# Apache Arrow writing nested types in parquet with C++

Tags: apache-arrow

unfortunately i found no c++ example which writes nested types like maps with Apache Arrow into parquet. The creation of the schemata is clear but not the arrow table creation part.

Has anyboy a hint or link on an example?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, Try to add a code example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To create a `StructArray` you can use the `StructArray::Make` method which takes in a vector of arrays for each of the fields:

```
arrow::DoubleBuilder heightBuilder;
heightBuilder.Append(68.3);
heightBuilder.Append(72.1);
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto heights, heightBuilder.Finish());

arrow::StringBuilder nameBuilder;
nameBuilder.Append("Alice");
nameBuilder.Append("Bob");
ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto names, nameBuilder.Finish());

arrow::FieldVector fields{arrow::field("height", arrow::float64()),
                          arrow::field("name", arrow::utf8())};

ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(auto array,
                      arrow::StructArray::Make({heights, names}, fields));
std::cout << array->ToString();
```